# issue linking to django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I currently have python installed at c:\python27

I currently have django installed (at least i followed the install dev version) at c:\development\python\

When I type and execute "python" from command prompt it starts python, as it should. However, when I type django-admin I get the error that it isn't recognized as an internal or external command. I'm wondering how I link this in so that it works

edited once more for clarity. I am attempting to run the command django-admin.py startproject projectname

Comment: Makes no sense. Please revise.

Comment: you're right, that looked terrible. Revised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read over the chapter on the admin in the Django Book: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/

The admin isn't a command that you run. You follow the directions there to "activate" it, and then use the standard `python manage.py runserver` to view your site. Then, just go to `/admin/`, and you'll see it in all it's glory.

**EDIT**

Oh. I thought you were trying to get the admin up and running, when you're really just trying to create your project in the first place. So:

If you've installed Django via easy_install, pip or simply running `python setup.py install` from the package's directory, then `django-admin.py` should have been added to your path. The only thing I can think of based on your question is that perhaps you're trying to run just `django-admin`? You do need the `.py` with it so make sure you use:

```
$ django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

If that's already the case, then two things. I doubt it's the case, but if you installed into a virtualenv, make sure that it's activated. Otherwise, you can try manually creating a symlink to it in some place like `/usr/local/bin`, e.g.:

```
$ ln -s /path/to/python/site-packages/django/django/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
```

Comment: I will check that link out. What prompted the question is that I am following along in [this](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=3360000&fromSeriesID=336) and at 7:51 he runs the command

django-admin.py startproject startthedark

when i run that, i get an error

Comment: He does it from the command line, not the python interpreter.

Comment: he the video or he me? if its he the video, i attempted that as well and i still got the error about it not being recognized

Comment: Explain precisely what you type- do you type django-admin.py or django-admin, and from the Python interpreter or from the command line?

Comment: @chris pratt, thanks for the update to your post, i think you and i are ALMOST on the same page. i followed the django instructions found here for the development version https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs#installing-the-development-version

Furthermore, i installed django-trunk to c:\development\python. whereas python is locaed at c:\python27. I did copy the django-admin.py file into c:\python27\tools\scripts but i am still unable to start a new django project

Comment: Well the key point is that you need to make sure django-admin.py is on your path. In Windows, you can just add the directory it's in to your PATH environment variable. Right-click Computer/My Computer, choose properties. In Windows Vista/7 you need one more step: click advanced system settings on the left. Then click Environment Variables... button.